# Which appium & appium inspector support iOS 16?

Tags: ios, appium-ios

Which appium & appium inspector support iOS 16?

I need to check v2022.9.1 is supported ?

I am not able to find the compatibility doc in appium

Answer (score 1):

The driver supplied with Appium 1.x is no longer maintained, so you will need Appium 2.x with the latest `xcuitest-driver` installed and you should be able to use iOS 16